# Enable/Disable Wifi on iOS simulator using selenium/Appium

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

I want to test some scenarios on my app when there is no Wifi connectivity, I need to first LogIn on good connection and then switch off the Wifi and continue doing some activities, Is it possible to disable and enable the network  by code? I am using Java/Selenium and Appium Server.

Comment: seems like we had a wanderer prior to this as well : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31279645/1746118

Comment: try **driver.toggleWifi()**. Its working for android device but don't know if its work on ios device

Answer (score 0):

I only can recommend you use the Network Link Conditioner app from Apple. For more information please read [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) blog.

Answer (score 0):

Some potential on this topic is contained over [here](http://appium.github.io/java-client/index.html?io/appium/java_client/NetworkConnectionSetting.html).
You can try creating a class of yours which includes an instance of `NetworkConnectionSetting` in the java-client of appium and set the flags accordingly by calling the built-in methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    ((HasNetworkConnection) appiumDriver).setConnection(Connection.ALL);
    assertEquals(Connection.ALL,((HasNetworkConnection) appiumDriver).getConnection());
//  NetworkConnectionSetting ncs = new NetworkConnectionSetting(false, true, true);
    ((HasNetworkConnection) appiumDriver).setConnection(Connection.NONE);
    assertEquals(Connection.NONE, ((HasNetworkConnection) appiumDriver).getConnection());
}
catch(Exception e)
{e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This class 'NetworkConnectionSetting' works on Android. As per the request, the need is for iOS app.