# How to turn ON/OFF wifi in ios real device using Appium

Tags: ios, selenium, automation, appium

> Using appium how to turn ON/OFF WIFI

Comment: Add Some HTML/screenshot /code to help you better.

Comment: By accessing control center. Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35124632

Answer (score 1):

There is no context to the question but I'll leave my solution. It might help someone. 
I'm using XCUITestDriver with python.

```
driver.activate_app('com.apple.Preferences')  # opens settings
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeCell[@name="Wi-Fi"]').click()  # click on WiFi 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeSwitch').click()  # click on the WiFi switch
driver.activate_app(<BundleID of your app>)  # back to your app
```

You can also access the value of switch to get the current state. Assuming you have a variable for the element

```
switch.get_attibute('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS read device,By appium/any automation tool, there is NO option to turn ON/OFF. iOS Device, Automation Scope is up to your app which is debug enabled. System Default apps or any apps which are downloaded from App Store are not accessible by automation.